# Mapping Domain Name to Tomcat application

Tags: linux, tomcat, dns, domain-name

I am having stand alone Linux Centos server with Static IP. I am running two tomcat application http://IP:8080/sampleapp, http://IP:8090/myapp. i can access that both application from internet. 
i bought domain from ipage.com. now i wanted to map http://sampleapp.com to  http://IP:8080/sampleapp and http://myapp.com to http://IP:8090/myapp.

I don't want to add another apache layer to forward port.

How can i map..? please help me

Comment: You can add nginx in front of Tomcats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a redirection in your ipage.com DNS setting which redirects your domain to your static IP.

But I would like to suggest you can run on port 80  to just make your link prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not very clear. However you can deploy both apps to the same port, like 80, and then use Tomcat virtual host to achieve what you need: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html